# Install specific version of python in Dockerfile on ubuntu

Tags: docker, pip

I have this in a Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt install -y python3-pip
```

how do I install a specific version of python though? Something like this:

```
RUN apt install -y python3-pip@python===3.6.7
```

I am looking for:

Python 3.6.7

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install latest version just use `RUN apt-get install python3` but if you want to install specific version of python you should do it manually for example were going to install python3.5.1:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl build-essential
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tgz
tar xzvf Python-3.5.1.tgz
cd Python-3.5.1
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

After installation completed set installed python as default one, e.g.:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python3.5.1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to install a specific version of Python over a simple Ubuntu, then why don't you directly use the official Python image corresponding to your needs ?

You can find all the supported images here : https://hub.docker.com/_/python

Comment: because I am to use Ubuntu

Comment: Well, there are some Python image based on Debian jessie. Wich is the Ubuntu base system. That's why i'm asking.  
Generally there isn't much difference between the need of an Ubuntu and a Debian.